# Find the html tag and extract text in html file

Tags: html-agility-pack

I need to get the title of html and it always returns null object. The html  format is:

```
 <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="gateway-toolbar"
 class="getway-toobar">..</div> 
              <span class="catalog_name">Catalog</span>
              <h1 id="page-title">The Content I want</h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

my code is below:

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString(myURLLink));
var root = html.DocumentNode;

var titleNodes = root.SelectNodes("//h1[@id='page-title']");
```

But the titleNodes is null. Please help!

var titleNodes= root.SelectNodes("//*[@id='page-title']");

I tried copy element xpath and it still does not work.

Comment: Your original path works for me by simply passing the string to the `LoadHtml` method. Are you sure you got the content? Put the result of the `DownloadString` in a variable and debug.

Comment: I used the same code to test a different URL page and it works fine. Could that be my webpage issue?

Comment: That is my assumption. And that is why I suggested you to download the content and inspect what you get.

Comment: Yeah. The URL requires login that's why it returns null. Thanks.